# Наследование событий в Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, c++-cli

Существует две формы сделанные с помощью Windows Forms на C++, для первой формы прописано событие, которое также нужно добавить во вторую форму. Есть ли способ как-нибудь наследовать это событие для второй формы, чтобы не дублировать код?

Вот пример событий, которые нужно добавить во вторую форму:

```
bool isDragging;
System::Drawing::Point offset;
System::Void Casino::AuthorisationWindow::AuthorisationWindow_MouseDown(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ e)
{
    isDragging = true;
    offset.X = e->X;
    offset.Y = e->Y;
}

System::Void Casino::AuthorisationWindow::AuthorisationWindow_MouseMove(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ e)
{
    if (isDragging)
    {
        Point currentScreenPosition = PointToScreen(Point(e->X, e->Y));
        Location = Point(currentScreenPosition.X - offset.X, currentScreenPosition.Y - offset.Y);
    }
}

System::Void Casino::AuthorisationWindow::AuthorisationWindow_MouseUp(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ e)
{
    isDragging = false;
}
```

Comment: Стандартный способ: выносим дублирующийся код в метод (класс) и далее используем этот метод (класс).

Comment: Получается нужно создать отдельный класс именно под этот фрагмент, а в другой форме также сделать класс, который будет наследовать первый?

Comment: Примечание: вот этот часто встречающийся код с тремя событиями (MouseDown, MouseMove, MouseUp) принципиально неправильный. Зажмите клавишу мышки, начните двигать, нажмите Alt+Tab не отпуская мышь, отожмите клавишу мыши. Вернитесь на форму - вуаля, баг.

Comment: Как вам будет удобней. Можно сделать базовую форму с обработкой этих событий. А уже от неё унаследовать две рабочие формы.

Comment: Правильность кода в данном случае мне не принципиальна, это проект для универа, который досконально тестировать на баги никто не будет

Comment: Попробую реализовать, спасибо за идею